# cannot write variables on the summation of cplex java

Tags: java, cplex

I have been working on a mathematical model for 3 months. I have a constraint like this:

[image]

Where x and y are decision variables, p is a parameter.

I wrote my mathematical model using Java, I tried a lot of things but all of them doesn’t work correctly or gives error. 
Would you please help me?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did you get?

Comment: Have you tried with OPL ? That could be easier.